# How to specify csv delimiter when using \o in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using

```
\o /some/file/path/output.csv
```

How can the delimiter be specified?  It seems to default to pipe `|` but my data contains that character thus breaking the csv output.

Comment: `\copy` might be a more flexible way to generate a CSV export

Comment: thx I did end up using `copy` - since needed it before the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the field separator with...

```
\pset fieldsep ','
```

> **fieldsep**
>
> Specifies the field separator to be used in unaligned output format. That way one can create, for example, tab- or comma-separated output, which other programs might prefer. To set a tab as field separator, type \pset fieldsep '\t'. The default field separator is '|' (a vertical bar).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html